# What are the sizes of tword, oword and yword operands?

Tags: assembly, nasm, cpu-word, yasm, word-size

What are the sizes of `tword`, `oword` and `yword` operands, as used in the [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html)/[YASM manual](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/manual.html)? And on a related note, is there a trick or underlying idea to these names? Is there a way by which bigger word sizes are given logical names?

I know that while word sizes may differ between systems, a NASM `word` is 2 bytes, `dword` is double that (4 bytes), `qword` is a quad word (8 bytes), but... is `tword` a *triple word* (6 bytes)? And for `oword` and `yword` I can't even think of a plausible meaning.

Note that it is probably an easy question, but I couldn't find an answer. In the NASM and YASM manuals these sizes are not explained, not even at the `DQ`, `DT`, `DY`, `RESQ`, `REST`, `RESY` pseudo-instructions. I read somewhere that MASM uses a similar system, but could not find anything on that either.

---

Edit: Based on the answers, this is the complete list:

- 1 byte (8 bit): `byte`, `DB`, `RESB`
- 2 bytes (16 bit): `word`, `DW`, `RESW`
- 4 bytes (32 bit): `dword`, `DD`, `RESD`
- 8 bytes (64 bit): `qword`, `DQ`, `RESQ`
- 10 bytes (80 bit): `tword`, `DT`, `REST`
- 16 bytes (128 bit): `oword`, `DO`, `RESO`, `DDQ`, `RESDQ`
- 32 bytes (256 bit): `yword`, `DY`, `RESY`
- 64 bytes (512 bit): `zword`, `DZ`, `RESZ`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking at [the nasm source](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/blob/master/modules/parsers/nasm/nasm-token.re), it looks like:

- 'oword'/'DO' is 8 times as big as "word" (O for "**o**ctoword"), synonymous with dqword ("double-quad"); that would be 128 bits, corresponding to the size of an SSE vector register.
- 'tword'/'DT' is 80 bits (T for "**t**en bytes"), the full size of an Intel x87 floating point register.
- 'yword'/'DY' is 256 bits, and the Y is presumably mnemonic for the YMM names of the 256-bit vector registers in the Intel AVX extensions.
- 'zword'/'DZ' is 512 bits, Z for the ZMM names of the 512-bit vector registers in the Intel AVX-512 extensions.

So, it's not exactly a logical naming convention; "it just growed".

Comment: This is the first time I know *YWORD* (*DY*?). Is it NASM/YASM or Intel specific (i.e.: not or not yet a standard)? And is there other keywords for 128-bit data?

Comment: No idea, probably not standard. For NASM, DO == DDQ, OWORD == DQWORD

Comment: @Jay: It's a NASM thing.  (MASM and gas `.intel_syntax` use a similar naming convention for memory-operand size overrides, e.g. `vmovdqa ymmword ptr [rdi], ymm0`.  You usually only see that in disassembly output; I can't think of a case where the memory operand width is ambiguous for a vector instruction, since at least one operand is always a register.)

Comment: `o` is used by Intel for `cqo`, but vector instructions use `dq` instead of `o` (e.g. `punpckhqdq`).  See also [my answer on a recent duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860003/how-much-bytes-does-resb-resw-resd-resq-allocates-in-nasm/44860059#44860059)

Answer (score 11):

I have checked it with two approaches for NASM: source code and empirical.

**Source code**

Source at: http://repo.or.cz/w/nasm.git

Then:

```
git grep -C2 tword
```

And we [fall upon](http://repo.or.cz/w/nasm.git/blob/3db63b96ecf79344b9c2618616e4be7c99720a18:/assemble.c#l266):

```
switch (size) {
case 1:
    return "byte";
case 2:
    return "word";
case 4:
    return "dword";
case 8:
    return "qword";
case 10:
    return "tword";
case 16:
    return "oword";
case 32:
    return "yword";
case 64:
    return "zword";
default:
    return "???";
}
```

**Empirical**

`git log -p` and `git tag --contains` tell me that `zword` was added in 2.11, and since I'm on 2.10 and lazy, I'll omit that one.

On our `.asm` file:

```
section .bss
resb1 resb 1
resw1 resw 1
resq1 resq 1
rest1 rest 1
reso1 reso 1
resy1 resy 1
; Just to read the objdump better.
resb2 resb 1
```

Then compile and:

```
objdump -D -j .bss main.o
```

gives:

```
00000000 <resb1>:
    ...

00000001 <resw1>:
    ...

00000003 <resd1>:
3:  00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

00000007 <resq1>:
    ...

0000000f <rest1>:
    ...

00000019 <reso1>:
    ...

00000029 <resy1>:
    ...

00000049 <resb2>:
    ...
```

If we take the differences between each position, we reach the same conclusion as before.

**zword menemonic**

For the `ZMM` registers added by AVX-512: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512

I wonder what Intel will do when the letters of the alphabet end.