# How can I store a 16 byte number into memory in assembly?

Tags: memory, assembly, cpu-registers

```
section .bss
   length equ 16
   number: resb length
```

This works only with 64 bits:

```
mov qword[number], 43271
```

This is represented of only 8 byte (64 bit). I need to store values in memory in 128 bit, but I've no idea how I can do that.

Thanks

Comment: You could just do more stores

Comment: Or use SSE loads/stores  (e.g. [`MOVDQU`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQU.html)).

Comment: Second that. Like `mov qword[number], 43271` + `mov qword[number+8], 54382`.

Comment: @PaulR: `MOVDQU` does not handle immediate values.

Comment: @zx485: sure - it would be a very long instruction if it did.

Comment: According to this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063840/what-are-the-sizes-of-tword-oword-and-yword-operands
Why doesn't works this command?
`number do 11`
It returns: "Integer supplied to a DT, DO or DY instruction?"

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is to use two store instructions, one for each half:

```
mov qword [number], 1234
mov qword [number+8], 4567
```