# How many bytes do RESB, RESW, RESD, RESQ allocate in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

`DB` allocates in chunks of 1 byte.

`DW` allocates in chunks of 2 bytes.

`DD` allocates in chunks of 4 bytes.

`DQ` allocates in chunks of 8 bytes.

So I assume that:

`RESB 1` allocates 1 byte.

`RESW 1` allocates 2 bytes.

`RESD 1` allocates 4 bytes.

`RESQ 1` allocates 8 bytes.

Am I correct?

---

The [documentation](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.2) doesn't say much:

> 3.2.2 RESB and Friends: Declaring Uninitialized Data
>
> RESB, RESW, RESD, RESQ, REST, RESO, RESY and RESZ are designed to be
>   used in the BSS section of a module: they declare uninitialized
>   storage space. Each takes a single operand, which is the number of
>   bytes, words, doublewords or whatever to reserve. As stated in section
>   2.2.7, NASM does not support the MASM/TASM syntax of reserving uninitialized space by writing DW ? or similar things: this is what it
>   does instead. The operand to a RESB-type pseudo-instruction is a
>   critical expression: see section 3.8.
>
> For example:
>
> buffer:         resb    64              ; reserve 64 bytes
>
> wordvar:        resw    1               ; reserve a word
>
> realarray       resq    10              ; array of ten reals
>
> ymmval:         resy    1               ; one YMM register
>
> zmmvals:        resz    32              ; 32 ZMM registers

Comment: yes, you're correct.  The docs seem pretty clear to me.

Comment: You need to think about what you have written.  `RESB 64` clearly says "reserve 64 things that are 1 byte in length"

Comment: @David Hoelzer Yes I noticed that, but the documentation only speaks clearly about  `resb` and not the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear about the documentation. Do you not know what they mean when they say "word"? This section is meant to be read *after* reading [the previous section](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1), since it uses the same type suffixes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Am I correct?

yes.

The size suffixes are consistent throughout NASM, for `d*` and `res*`.  They match x86 instruction mnemonic suffixes for byte to qword.  (e.g. `psubd` works with packed dword elements).

There's even an instruction mnemonic that uses `o` (oct-word):  [`cqo`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CWD:CDQ:CQO.html).

y and z size suffixes obviously match ymm and zmm register sizes, even though the instruction mnemonics are now things like [`VBROADCASTI32X8`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VPBROADCAST.html) because of AVX512 masking granularity.

Comment: Well, more or less consistent. Intel occasionally comes up with silly and confusing terminology like `dq` (double-quad) words instead of owords. `rest` reserves ten _bytes_ and not a pentaword . Still, I would advocate checking the listing and or debugger to see actual result in this case.

Comment: @doynax: that's why I said it matches mnemonics up to qword, because of `movdqa/u`, `movntdq/dqa`, and the amusingly named `punpckhqdq` (unpack qword to dqword), and so on.  Or `cmpxchg16b`.  Intel's documentation never talks about `m80` x87 operands as TBYTE or penta-word or anything like that, they just say 80-bit if they name it at all.  Or for example ["18-digit packed BCD integer"](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/FBSTP.html).

Comment: Also related: [What are the sizes of tword, oword and yword operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12063840) / [What comes after QWORD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39645078)